# Forcing file_get_contents() not to render php codes as plain text

Tags: php

How can I get expected output from example below?

**Note**: I'm using `$content = file_get_contents('content.php');` to use content where and when possible so it is not a direct output on screen. `include()` breaks the pages.

**content.php**

```
<p>Hello <?php echo 'World!'; ?></p>
```

**reader.php**

```
<b>Message from another file:</b> <?php echo file_get_contents('content.php'); ?>
```

Output of code above is:

```
Message from another file: Hello <?php echo 'World!'; ?>
```

Instead of (expected):

```
Message from another file: Hello World!
```

Comment: use `include()` instead.

Comment: `include('content.php')` instead of `file_get_contents()`. The latter's purpose is to read a file from disk, not to import PHP code.

Comment: Sorry guys, my mistake. I added a note regarding to `include()` so include doesn't work in my case.

Comment: teh funtion echo file_get_contents just read the file contents so it prints what file content.php has in it not the result of the exectuoion of teh scriot .Is like you open the content.php in notepad and read it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `<?php include('content.php');`

> file_get_contents — Reads entire file into a string

[PHP.net file_get_contents - manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

> The include statement includes and evaluates the specified file.

[PHP.net include - manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Try making content.php into a file that has a function that returns the content you want (you may want to have parameters). Simply require the file then call the function and save the output.

Example:

**content.php**

```
function get_content($world){
  return '<p>Hello ' . $world . '</p>';
}
```

**reader.php**

```
<?php 
require('content.php');
$content = get_content('world');
?>
<b>Message from another file:</b> <?php echo $content; ?>
```

Comment: Sorry @Billy. My mistake. I added a note regarding to `include()` so include doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot use `include` (though I don't understand fully why), but want the file to be parsed and executed as PHP code, you can use eval

```
<b>Message from another file:</b> <?php eval(file_get_contents('content.php')); ?>
```

But the file content.php should not contain `<?php` and `?>` tags, as stated at http://php.net/eval.